# Automatically creating projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates, mvvmcross

I'm working on cross-platform plugins for MvvmCross. Most of the time is spent recreating the same structure of projects over and over again, including nuget entries, changing output directories, adding files, etc. How do I automatically create all these projects in one swoop? Ideally, I would just say Add New Plugin, enter "Stopwatch" and have everything automatically create.

[image]

Comment: This may be the answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx

Comment: Or try http://adriansudbury.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/ninja-coders-for-mvvmcross-part-2.html?m=1 ?

Answer (score 0):

@Stuart has already commented but the tool recommended is what you want so I'll give it as an answer.

I've been using NinjaCoder (a Visual Studio Addin for MvvmCross) for my recent projects and it pretty much covers everything you could need to create a solution out the box. It was created by [Adrian Sudbury](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/adrian%20sudbury1/?ws=usercard-hover) and it can be downloaded from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/618b51f0-6de8-4f85-95ce-a50c658c7767).

Tutorial links can be found on the download page, but if not the blog posts regarding views, viewmodels and plugins can be found [here](http://adriansudbury.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/ninja-coders-for-mvvmcross-part-3.html).